# Interrupting $html.= ' for IF statement

Tags: php

Hi Stack Exchange Community,

I'm looking to understand how to insert an IF statement inside the code below:

```
$html.= '<span class="cat">In <a href="'. $typeLink . '">' . $terms_string . '</a></span>';
```

Essentially, I would like to insert a glyph just before the hyperlink that changes based on the value of $terms_string (using IF and ELSEIF). I thought the line below might be close to what I need, but I'm unsure if I'm accurately switching between PHP and HTML (definitely user error, but is it a syntax error?).

```
$html.= '<span class="cat">In '. if($terms_string === "Articles") { glyph HTML code }; .' <a href="'. $typeLink . '">' . $terms_string . '</a></span>';
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more general PHP than anything WordPress specific.

[String concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) occurs whenever you combining two stings with the `.` operator. During string concatenation some basic PHP keywords will not apply and you'll need to use the shorthand equivalent instead. In this case you can use the [ternary (conditional) operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$html.= '<span class="cat">In '. ( $terms_string === "Articles" ) ? 'glyph HTML code' : '' .' <a href="'. $typeLink . '">' . $terms_string . '</a></span>';
```

A better, more readable format may be breaking up the HTML output into multiple strings:

```
$html.= '<span class="cat">In ';

if( "Articles" == $terms_string ) {
    $html .= 'glyph HTML code';
}

$html .= '<a href="'. $typeLink . '">' . $terms_string . '</a></span>';
```

Comment: Hi Howdy_McGee, thanks so much for the clarification. I'm new to PHP, and your explanation not only makes sense but encourages me to keep learning. I appreciate your time to help me out.